# "Popular Articles" Admin Module - Why do some articles have blue number of hits in the list?

Tags: module, articles, administrator

In the "Popular Articles" admin Module in the Control Panel - Why do some articles have blue number of hits in the list? What does this mean?

I have highlighted the area in red.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla colour codes the article count based on the number of hits.

It looks like over 100 hits is colour coded blue, over 1,000 hits is orange and over 10,000 hits is red.